# Problem. python scrape with requests + selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

[CODE IS HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxD82.png)

Hi guys

I have some problem with **scraping** this dynamic site (https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/)
I need to get all the links to the home sale ads

I used selenium to load the page and get links to ads after that I move the page down to load new ads. After the new ads are loaded, I start to parse all the links on the page and write them to the list again.
But the data in the list is not updated and the script continues to work with the links that were on the page before scrolling down.

By the way, I set a check so that the script is executed until the last announcement on the site appears in the list, the link to which I found out in advance

How can this problem be corrected?

```
def get_link_info():

    try:
        url = "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path=r'C:\Users\kk\Desktop\scrape_house\drivers\chromedriver.exe',
            options=options
        )

        driver.get(url)

        req = requests.get(url)
        req.encoding = 'utf8'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
        articles = soup.find_all("div", class_="content")

        links_urls = []
        for article in articles:
            house_url = article.find("a").get("href")
            links_urls.append(house_url)
            #print(links_urls)

        first_link_number = links_urls[-2].split("-")[-1]
        first_link_number = first_link_number[1:]
        #print(first_link_number)

        last_link_number = links_urls[-1].split("-")[-1]
        last_link_number = last_link_number[1:]
        #print(last_link_number)

        html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        html.send_keys(Keys.END)
        check = "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/kvartira-v-elitnom-komplekse-s-unikalynym-sadom-o21751"

        for a in links_urls:
            if a != check:

                for article in articles:
                    house_url = article.find("a").get("href")
                    links_urls.append(house_url)

                html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
                html.send_keys(Keys.END)
                print(links_urls[-1])


            else:
                print(links_urls[0], links_urls[-1])
                print("all links are ready")
```

Comment: @Дмитрий You have one answer. Leave some feedback if it works or not. This is how this site works. You ask, people answer you and you accept/upvote answers. YOu leave some comments in the case of errors.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers. You don't need to mix `selenium,requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. Just `selenium` is enough. When you are scrolling infinitely, you need to remove duplicate elements before adding them to your list.
You can try this. This should work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def get_link_info():
    all_links = []
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get('https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/')
        time.sleep(3)
        old_links = set()  # Empty Set
        while True:
            # Scroll to get more ads
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,3825)", "")
            # Wait for new ads to load
            time.sleep(8)
            links_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]//a')  # Find Elements
            ans = set(links_divs) - set(old_links)  # Remove old elements
            for link in ans:
                # Scroll to the link. 
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", link)
                fir = link.get_attribute('href')
                all_links.append(fir)
            # Remove Duplicates
            old_links = links_divs
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

get_link_info()
```